# Unable to print file contents in swift

Tags: swift

I'm back once more with another issue. In my attempt to learn swift Ive decided that writing a bunch of small, random, playground scripts, that i can go back and use as references later on is a good place to start.

## goal

What I'm working on now, is a small script that uses 2 different ways to read the same file, printing the file contents when finished.

Using quite a few tips I found here on stack (aswell as the official docs) Ive managed to piece together a script that should do the above goal. (Please excuse the heavy commenting, as these are references)

```
//Import for use of NSString
import Foundation

//ATTEMPT #1
//Set file locations
let location = NSString(string:"/Users/me/Desktop/file.txt").stringByExpandingTildeInPath
//Make fileContent = data within file
let fileContent = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
//print content of file
print("The file contains:\n", fileContent, "\n")

//ATTEMPT #2
//set filename
let filename = "file.txt"
//set document path
let documentsPath = "/Users/me/Desktop"
let destinationPath = documentsPath + "/" + filename
//read file
let data: NSData? = NSData(contentsOfFile: destinationPath)
print("The file contains:\n", data, "\n")
```

## Issue

I have created the file in the given location, Yet no matter how i try to work either bit of code, I recieve 'nil' as my file contents (which is simply 'hello world')

The file is a simple text file, UTF8 made with textwrangler. There is no free space before or after my string in the file. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Changed:

```
//Set file locations
let location = NSString(string:"/Users/l8nit3/Documents/file.txt").stringByExpandingTildeInPath
//Make fileContent = data within file
let fileContent = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

to:

```
//Set file locations
let location = NSString(string:"/Users/l8nit3/Documents/file.txt")
//Make fileContent = data within file
let fileContent = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: location as String, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

to remove the use of .stringByExpandingTildeInPath as per suggestions

Comment: Actually not anymore. Playground it is sandboxed

Comment: You will have to test it using an actual project

Comment: Why are you using stringByExpandingTildeInPath without any tilde?

Comment: To be honest, as im very new to this language, that part was found here on stack, which is why I attempted two different ways. Thank you for the info on the sandbox, is the sandboxed 'root' somewhere i can simply access and copy my file there?

Comment: Yes you can print documents folder path and use the finder Go to Folder Shift-Command-G. For the simulator. You can't do it for an actual device

Comment: can you phrase this as an answer? Then i can accept it and you can get the 'reputation' for providing a great answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually not anymore. Playground it is sandboxed so you need to test using an actual project. You can place a file inside playground  documents folder path for testing using Finder's   Go to Folder (Shift-Command-G) to locate it.